# How to eliminate duplicates while looping through JSON array

Tags: jquery, json, while-loop, frontend

I will be getting this JSON as  response from server

```
var responsefromserver = 
    {
    "Restaurants": [
        {
            "RestrntArea": "Home"
        },
        {
            "RestrntArea": "Office"

        },
        {
            "RestrntArea": "Office"

        }
    ]
};
```

Could you please let me know , how to  eliminate duplicates from the above while looping it in front end ??

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/720/

Comment: That's not JSON. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, unless you're talking about something *in a string*, it's not JSON.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array and so, so, so, so many others. Please search before posting.

Comment: Hi @Preethi, what constitutes a duplicate? Duplicate key, duplicate value or both key and value being the same?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion , duplicate key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
 var responsefromserver = {
        "Restaurants": [{
            "RestrntArea": "Home"
        }, {
            "RestrntArea": "Office"
        }, {
            "RestrntArea": "Office"
        }]
    };

    var html = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < responsefromserver.Restaurants.length; i++) {
        var name = responsefromserver.Restaurants[i].RestrntArea;
        if(html.indexOf(name)==-1)
              html.push(name);
    }

    alert(html.join(''));
```